# make class.getResource("/some.properties") work

Tags: java, jsp, websphere-liberty

This JSP

```
<html><head><title><%=application.getServerInfo() %></title></head><body>

  <%= javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.class.getResource("/test.properties") %>

</body></html>
```

outputs on Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

```
file:/projekte/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/lib/test.properties
```

On IBM WebSphere Liberty/20.0.0.9 I got null.

How can I load the resource?

I tried with

```
test.properties in usr/servers/luna/lib/global
```

and

```
<library id="tr">
   <folder dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/tr" />
</library>    

<webApplication location="tr.war" type="war">
      <classloader classProviderRef="tr" />
   </webApplication>
```

I would not use ServletContext.getResource() because my actual problem is within an ear/lib class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not classProviderRef, but commonLibraryRef.

```
<classloader commonLibraryRef="tr" />
```

Still, the resource is only found if getResource() is called on a class from *within* the application, e.g. the compiled JSP `com.ibm._jsp._resource`.

```
<%= getClass().getResource("/test.properties") %>
```

outputs

```
file:/wlp/wlp-javaee8-20/usr/servers/luna/lib/tr/test.properties
```